# How to change the code to select an existing worksheet not add a new?

Tags: vba, excel

Pretty much new here and new in VBA as well!

I have a script, which I would like to change to write the requested date to an existing worksheet not to add a new one. Can you please help me. The code:

```
    Private Sub getlng()
    Define the API URL you want to call.
'   Here the URL is fixed, but you can always in the code add dynamically a set    of parameters.
'Dim tol, ig As String
Dim url As String: url = "https://transparency.entsog.eu/api/v1/operationaldatas.xml?from=2017-01-01&to=2017-02-22&limit=-1&indicator=Firm%20Technical%2CFirm%20Booked%2CInterruptible%20Technical%2CInterruptible%20Booked%2CInterruptible%20Available%2CRenomination%2CNomination%2CAllocation%2CPhysical%20Flow&pointKey=LNG-00004%2CLNG-00006%2CLNG-00007%2CLNG-00008%2CLNG-00012%2CLNG-00013%2CLNG-00014%2CLNG-00015%2CLNG-00017%2CLNG-00018%2CLNG-00019%2CLNG-00021%2CLNG-00022%2CLNG-00023%2CLNG-00024%2CLNG-00026%2CLNG-00027%2CLNG-00029%2CLNG-00030%2CLNG-00045%2CLNG-00047%2CLNG-00049%2CITP-00424%2CLNG-00042%2CLNG-00032%2CLNG-00034%2CLNG-00044%2CLNG-00038%2CLNG-00010%2CLNG-00039%2CLNG-00041%2CLNG-00057%2CLNG-00056"
' Create a HTTP request to retrieve the data from the TP
Dim oHTTP As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Set oHTTP = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
oHTTP.Open Method:="GET", url:=url, async:=False
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; "
oHTTP.Option(WinHttp.WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
oHTTP.send
Dim success As Boolean
success = oHTTP.waitForResponse()
If Not success Then
Debug.Print "DOWNLOAD FAILED!"
Exit Sub
ElseIf success Then
Debug.Print "DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL"
End If
' The response text is, in our example, a XML document.
Dim responseText As String
responseText = oHTTP.responseText
Set oHTTP = Nothing
' We can load this text as a VBA XML object
Dim xml As New DOMDocument
Call xml.LoadXML(responseText)
' After that, the object can be manipulated in any way you want. In the example, we simply export it to Excel in a workbook.
Dim wsn As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wsn = wb.Worksheets.Count
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(wsn))
Dim row, col As Integer
Dim headers As IXMLDOMNodeList: Set headers = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("./meta/item[4]/property")
' Here it's simply iterating along the column, or header names, of the API
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To headers.Length - 1
ws.Cells(1, i + 1) = headers.Item(i).Text
Next
Dim items As IXMLDOMNodeList: Set items = xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes
' And then we list every row found and write its attributes in Excel.
row = 1
Dim j As Integer
Dim e As IXMLDOMElement
For Each e In items
row = row + 1
For j = 0 To e.ChildNodes.Length - 1
ws.Cells(row, j + 1) = e.ChildNodes(j).Attributes.getNamedItem("value").NodeValue
Next
Next
' Formatting
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.UsedRange, , xlYes).Name = "data"
Dim data_table As ListObject
Set data_table = ws.ListObjects("data")
data_table.ListColumns.Add.Name = "datum"
data_table.ListColumns("datum").DataBodyRange.formula = "=TEXT(LEFT([periodFrom],10),""éééé.hh.nn"")"

'képlet sablon a táblázat feltöltéséhez

'=IF(SUMIFS(data[[value]:[value]];data[[datum]:[datum]];$A402;data[[pointLabel]:[pointLabel]];$B$1;data[[directionKey]:[directionKey]];$B$2;data[[indicator]:[indicator]];E$4)=0;(SUMIFS(data[[value]:[value]];data[[datum]:[datum]];$A402;data[[pointLabel]:[pointLabel]];$B$1;data[[directionKey]:[directionKey]];$B$2;data[[indicator]:[indicator]];"Nomination"));SUMIFS(data[[value]:[value]];data[[datum]:[datum]];$A402;data[[pointLabel]:[pointLabel]];$B$1;data[[directionKey]:[directionKey]];$B$2;data[[indicator]:[indicator]];E$4))

'=SUMIFS(data[[value]:[value]];data[[datum]:[datum]];$A5;data[[pointLabel]:[pointLabel]];$B$1;data[[directionKey]:[directionKey]];$B$2;data[[indicator]:[indicator]];B$4)

End Sub
```

I tried to change the line where it adds the new worksheet, to:

```
SET ws = wb.Worksheets("worksheetname").Select
```

but it gets me error 9.

Don't know how to change it to work.
Regards,

Comment: You don't need the `Select`. Change your `SET ws = wb.Worksheets("worksheetname").Select` to `SET ws = wb.Worksheets("worksheetname")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't use `wsn` elsewhere, simply replace this section:

```
Dim wsn As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wsn = wb.Worksheets.Count
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(wsn))
```

With

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("worksheetname")
```